# Why is my c++ program terminating with no output in Eclipse but works in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, eclipse

My program was running in visual studio on Windows, but when I tried working on it in Eclipse on Ubuntu, it would terminate when I tried to run, without showing any output at all.

Eclipse is using the Linux GCC toolkit.

I have no compiler errors or warnings or anything, the console just shows the bit saying it terminated and then blank.

I went into debugging and came up with

Shop [1188] [cores: 1]
    Thread [1] 1188 [core: 1] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault) 
        0x7ffff7b78bca
        std::string::assign() at 0x7ffff7b79ff6 
        operator=() at basic_string.h:542 0x402f00
        fillInventory() at shop.cpp:364 0x402f00
        main() at shop.cpp:73 0x401a29

I *think* that it's not opening the input file, but I'm not sure  ... main and prototypes are below:

```
input file      :ball_inventory.txt
output file     :ball_reportData.txt
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//CLASSES and STRUCTURES
struct inventory
{
    string name;            //name of item
    int cost;               //cost of item
    int stock;              //items in stock
    int deficit;            //items ordered but not provided when out of stock
};


//PROTOTYPES

//Receive and validate input for yes/no prompts.
char yesNo();
//Display shop's logo
void logo();
//Display the low level item menu
void lowLevelMenu(int limit, inventory lowLevelInv[]);
//perform a purchase action for a single individual
int purchase(int limit, inventory lowLevelInv[], int itemTally[]);
//populate the inventory array with name, price, stock, data, initialize deficit to 0.
int fillInventory(ifstream &fin, inventory lowLevelInv[]);
//sort the inventory array by the day's deficit
void sortByDeficit(inventory lowLevelInv[], int limit);



//BODY
/*  
*   Function Procedure:
*   1.  Prompt "customer 1" user for purchases
*   3.  Update group total
*   3.  Loop until there are no more "customers"
*   4.  Output group total
*   5. If no more groups, prompt for password.
*   6. At end of day, output to file, 1 line per item: name, stock, deficit.
*/
int main()
{
    const int INV = 20;                                     //sets size of item[] and parallel arrays
    char confirm = 'n';                                     //holds user response to y/n prompts
    int groupTot;                                           //Group's total cost
    ifstream invSrc;                                        //inventory resource file
    ofstream    ball_reportData;                            //output file for report
    int limit;                                              //number of populated elements in arrays
    string password = "98765";                              //sets manager password
    string passCheck;                                       //user input to be checked against password
    bool exitAllow = 0;                                     //allows program to generate report and exit
    int itemTally[INV];                                     //tally of items ordered by a user
    inventory lowLevelInv[INV];                             //contains inventory information for the low level inventory

    invSrc.open("ball_inventory.txt");                      //open inventory file, populate arrays, close inventory file.
    /*LINE 73*/ limit = fillInventory(invSrc, lowLevelInv);
    invSrc.close();

    logo();                                                 //display shop logo

    while(!exitAllow)                                       //continue running until password is entered to set exitAllow to true
    {
        groupTot = 0;                                       //initialize group total due to 0;
        groupTot += purchase(limit, lowLevelInv, itemTally);                //prompt first customer for purchases and update group total
        do
        {
            cout<<"Are there any more orders for this group? y/n: ";        //check for more customers
            confirm = yesNo();
            if(confirm == 'y')                                              //prompt additional users and update total for each
            {
                groupTot += purchase(limit, lowLevelInv, itemTally);
            }
        }while(confirm == 'y');

        cout<<"The group's total is: "<<groupTot<<" denarii.";          //output total for group

        cout<<"\n\nAre you done for the day?";                                  //confirm for more groups to calculate
        confirm = yesNo();
        while(confirm == 'y')
        {
            cout<<"Enter your password:";
            cin>>passCheck;
            if(password != passCheck)
            {
                cout<<"Invalid password, try again? ";
                confirm = yesNo();
            }
            else
            {
                exitAllow = 1;
                confirm = 'n';
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<limit; i++)
    {
        cout << lowLevelInv[i].stock << endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<limit; i++)
    {
        cout << lowLevelInv[i].deficit << endl;
    }
    cout << string(20, '-')<<endl;
    sortByDeficit(lowLevelInv, limit);



    ball_reportData.open("ball_reportData.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i<limit; i++)
    {
        ball_reportData << lowLevelInv[i].name << endl;
        ball_reportData << lowLevelInv[i].stock << endl;
        ball_reportData << lowLevelInv[i].deficit << endl;
    }

    cout<<"\n\nPress Enter to finish...";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return(0);
}
```

Fill Inventory:

```
int fillInventory(ifstream &fin, inventory lowLevelInv[])
{
    string name = "junk";               //name to be input to itemArray
    string cost;
    string stock;                           //cost to be input to costArray
    int i = 0;                              //incrementer
    stringstream convert;               //string stream used to input string to int
    int max=0;                                  //Number of elements filled in array

    while(name != "none")               //until "none" in file, fill name/cost arrays
    {
        getline(fin, name);             //get name line
        getline(fin, cost);             //get cost line
        getline(fin, stock);
        if(name != "none")
        {
/*LINE 364*/    lowLevelInv[i].name = name;         //output to name array
            convert<<cost;                  //fill stringstream
            convert >> lowLevelInv[i].cost; //output stringstream to cost array
            convert.clear();                //clear EOF(?) flag
            convert<<stock;                 //fill stringstream
            convert >> lowLevelInv[i].stock;    //output stringstream to cost array
            convert.clear();                //clear EOF(?) flag
            lowLevelInv[i].deficit = 0;         //set initial deficit

            max++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: How can we possibly answer this question with the information you've given us?

Comment: What compiler are you using with eclipse? we have nothing to work with, so we cant help.

Comment: Eclipse and VS are probably using different compilers but more information is needed to provide a useful answer. Try editing with eclipses compiler and the line which causes the crash.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you'd need ... I'm new to programming and newer to eclipse. So ... yeah. I used the Linux GCC toolchain to make it, but is that the compiler?

Comment: The question you've asked is akin to asking "I tried something in one car and it didn't work in another.  What's wrong?"

Comment: John: That may be, but I'm trying to figure out what I need to ask. I am in deep water and I can only doggy paddle, so I'm sorry.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I can't figure out what line is causing a crash, how can I do that?

Comment: @DanielBall:  Fair enough.  We need specifics.  We need to know what the code is -- keep it (small) [sscce.org] please -- what it is expected to do, and what it is actually doing.  We expect that you have already tried to figure out the problem on your own (by using a debugger and other assorted tools) and have narrowed the problem down to something that can be expressed in a specific, answeable question.

Comment: I've never written c++ in eclipse but in VS if you run the program with 'debug' and there is a runtime exception, it will break on the exception. If that isn't happening, set a break point and step through the code.

Comment: Well, I had already tried debugging but apparently I was doing it wrong. I think I found something ... give me a moment to change my question.

Comment: this is a really silly purpose for c++. c++ make sense for performance. why wouldn't you use a managed language for simple scripting like this?

Comment: @DanielBall: the error is _near_ line 364 in the `fillInventory()` function in shop.cpp.  Show us that function and functions related to it

Comment: OK, now set a breakpoint on the beginning of `fillInventory` and step through the code, line by line.  Observe the state of every variable at every step.  If you note a variable doing something you didn't expect, you're getting close to identifying the problem.  I would also pay special attention to incrementing `i` beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @FlavorScape: A: this is a project for a beginners c++ class, B: What's a managed language?

Comment: @JohnDibling I'm trying to step through from fillInventory, but when I look at the variables window, all I see is "optimized out" or {...} in the value column, even for i...

Comment: @DanielBall:  You are likely running a Release build.  Try debugging a Debug build

Comment: I had to go do it in visual studio for now, class soon. I'll try and get back to it after ... thanks for your help thus far.

Answer (score 6):

As guys at ["No Console Output (MinGW, CDT)"](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197552/) point out, this is probably (or at least sometimes) because Eclipse does not add PATH to MINGW\bin when launching the executable, so:

In the "Environment" tag, press "New", set it as:

- "Name:PATH"
- "Value:C:\MinGW\bin"

Comment: I'm running eclipse in Linux.

Comment: change the compiler to G++ then? the general subject should still apply

Comment: I guess I could, but then why would it have worked with other programs that I didn't have to do that for?